# How to achieve Vogue-style affixed date which changes on scroll in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, date, sticky

I'm an admirer of the Vogue website, and I'm looking to implement a specific element I found on their website. If you go to the following link:

http://www.vogue.co.uk/news

As you scroll down, the date sticks to the top of the page. This much I believe I know how to pull off, but what they also do is make the date change, corresponding to the date of the first article you're scrolling passed.

I'm curious, how is this done? Presumably there's some sort of anchor or trigger?

I'm trying to achieve this in WordPress (just to complicate matters :P).

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very much appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

if you inspect the css:

postions for side bar and headers are always fixed.

```
.sideBar, .header{
     position : fixed;
}
```

// in firefox you can notice

```
#ContentNavigation {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 44px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    transition: left 0.3s ease-out 0s, width 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    z-index: 10001;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap's JavaScript Lib contains something similar called **"Affix"**.

It sticks the nav element to the window top and changes the current button to the current content. The same principle is used for the Vogue Date Sticky.

**Have a look at it here:**
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

**And also check out the source on GitHub:**
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3.0.0-wip/js/affix.js

Looking at the source of the Vogue Site, all that is used is:

```
<h2 data-bind="html: GroupName" class="fixed" style="top: 50px; width: 1077px;">Thursday 1<sup>st</sup> August</h2>
```

…together with some JS (located [here](http://d3u12z27ui3vom.cloudfront.net/Build-Vogue-master/1947-879c27ae7cca/logic/article-listing-2012.generated.js)) which grabs the h2 headers and fixes them to the top "onscroll" at that pixel radius.

**So, for example:**

At the beginning the h2 looks like this:

```
<h2 data-bind="html: GroupName">Thursday 1<sup>st</sup> August</h2>
```

When the user scrolls over it, then the h2 tag will be converted into:

```
<h2 data-bind="html: GroupName" class="fixed" style="top: 50px; width: 1077px;">Thursday 1<sup>st</sup> August</h2>
```

***Notice*** that `class="fixed"` and the `style="..."` attributes got added. The h2 tag that got fixed prior to this one will be reset. jQuery is good at this if done right with careful use of the selectors (e.g. `var h2_elements = $('h2'); $('.fixed', h2_elements).removeClass('fixed');` or use something like `toggleClass('fixed')`).

**That's it :-)**

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. Yours particularly, Markus, it was very informative.

I've managed to achieve the affix part, but does anyone have any ideas on how I might achieve the date part in WordPress?

Comment: Since you're working with WordPress I assume you want to show different dates in a posts / articles overview list. Try to group the fetched data in date-order and put an h2 tag containing the date above each group. So divide the list into div containers, each for it's own date. Put an h2 tag above it. Give it a try. **Also have a look in the WordPress Docs:** [Creating an Archive Index](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index), [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), [Linking Posts Pages and Categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Linking_Posts_Pages_and_Categories).